# Unexpexted exception - apache ignite - Web Session Clustering

Tags: java, maven, session, ignite

I'm trying to setup a "Web Session Clustering" in Tomcat 7. I followed by http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.5/docs/web-session-clustering with replicated cacheMode. And I'm getting an exception:

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Cache for web sessions is not started (is it configured?): replicated
at org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter.init(WebSessionFilter.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4908)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5602)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:679)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:554)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1779)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1506)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:902)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:361)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.ocb.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.ocb.Logout</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.ignite.startup.servlet.ServletContextListenerStartup</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.ignite.cache.websession.WebSessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- You can also specify a custom URL pattern. -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>IgniteWebSessionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>IgniteConfigurationFilePath</param-name>
    <param-value>config/default-config.xml </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Specify the name of Ignite cache for web sessions. -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>IgniteWebSessionsCacheName</param-name>
    <param-value>replicated</param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

and my default-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
    <!-- Cache name. --> 
    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>

</bean>
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>

                            <!-- 
                                IP Address and optional port range.
                                You can also optionally specify an individual port.
                            -->
                            <value>192.168.5.15:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And ofcourse my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.flomedia</groupId>
<artifactId>OCB</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>OCB</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ignite configuration is incorrect. `CacheConfiguration` bean has to be provided as a part of `IgniteConfiguration` and also has to have the name specified:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
        <!-- Cache name. -->
        <property name="name" value="replicated"/>

        <!-- Cache mode. -->
        <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Discovery, etc... -->
</bean
```